# How to connect filename with the cell value in Excel and paste it formatted into Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an Excel file with a table where each row represents address and description of property; as well .jpg files - photos of buildings. Each .jpg filename starts with the number (for example 66_foto1.jpg) and the same number contains column "OBJECTID" in the table.

I would like to connect ID value from Excel table with the name of photo and to paste it into Word file. For now I have the code which allows me to paste different photos having the same ID one by one (for example 66_foto1.jpg, 66_foto2.jpg, 66_foto3.jpg):

```
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim objfolder As Object
    Dim objfile As Object
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim strpath As String
    Dim objsub As Object

    strpath = "C:\Users\xxx\"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objfolder = fso.GetFolder(strpath)

    For Each objfile In objfolder.Files
        If UCase(objfile.Name) Like "66_*" Then lCount = lCount + 1
    Next objfile
```

but I still need to convert 66_*.jpg into variable and create a loop.

[image: Excel Table]

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking with "convert 66_*.jpg" into a variable and create a loop. Can you perhaps provide a specific example?

Comment: Do you want a loop from 1 to 99, or did you want to read the OBJECTID column?

Comment: I would like to capture the information from the rows one by one. The OBJECTID contains specific numbers and .jpg files have the same numbers. For example, row 6 has OBJECTID = 66 and in the folder I have 3 photos with the names: 66_foto1.jpg, 66_foto2.jpg and 66_foto3.jpg. On the first page I need go write text and photo1 below, on the second page the same text and photo2 etc. Then on the 4th page info from the row 7.

Answer (score 0):

I have already supplied the code for the picture insertion into a Word document in answer to your earlier post on the same topic: [Copy paragraphs from Word into the next page if the condition is met (macro)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59152159/copy-paragraphs-from-word-into-the-next-page-if-the-condition-is-met-macro). Did you read it? Did you try it? Before any automation can be done, you need to at least say whether the process is being run from Word, or from Excel.